# Multiple calls to service not handling all requests

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a `Silverlight` app that uses `WCF` for communication with my `SQL Server` via `Entity Framework`. When I send multiple requests to the service it fails to send all. If I use the Callback event and send each request as the previous one completes all is well. How can I get this to work without this workaround?

Edited:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To someNumberOfTimesInLoop
  serv.CloseElement_IncAsync(Params...)
Next
```

So I wonder if it's a concurrency problem as they hit at the same time and the Id fields for these tables are not incremented in time?

I have added this code in my App.xaml.vb based on this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/olakarlsson/archive/2010/05/20/simultaneously-calling-multiple-methods-on-a-wcf-service-from-silverlight.aspx):

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Never run across that.  I have done some extreme testing and have never gotten it to fail, even when keeping 100 requests active for over ten minutes.  Perhaps there is something wrong with your code. Can you post more code, maybe the full call and callback?

Comment: @Steve, Thanks for confirming this is not the expected behavior. I will get back as soon as I can...

Comment: @Steve, here is how I was calling it originally and without the `Callback`, and it was failing. I didn't start using the `Callback` til it was failing and then only to process the next request. Is it a poss concurrency issue? Each time the `WCF` code call the new ID for this table?

Comment: The only thing else I have noticed that improved this was have each `UserControl` to have an instance of the service and it makes it own call with it's loading. Previously, I was using a loop to add all the calls to the server while the controls were added with the same loop, but the results are better this way. That sounds confusing - maybe... Thanks for helping.